# Angular JS - Automatically Page Scroll on Top on Loading Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, scrollbar

I am getting this minor problem.

I am using `http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html` is the angular extension for infinite scroll

And it is working fine but when i move to the end of the page and then if reload the page the scroll position is Always at the end of the page which is making `nginfinitescroll` to trigger again and again till it loads whole data.

So now what i want is how can i make scroll position at the top while controller is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```
scrollableElmt.scrollTop = 0;
```

After DOM ready, but before the infinite scroll listener gets applied.

Note that I used the raw DOM element, in jQuery you could do:

```
jqScrollableElmt.scrollTop(0);
```

Don't know if you are using jQuery or not

Comment: I am using jquery but i am using angular js and want to `Scrolltop` while initiating particular `controller`

Comment: You can do that - can you show some code for the template and controller in your question?

Comment: `app.controller('clientController', function($scope, $http){
$scope.loadMore();
$scope.loadMore = function() {
      if(!$scope.busy){
      $scope.busy = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      $scope.clients.push($scope.rcvddata[$scope.clients.length-1]);
            $scope.loading = false;
           }
           $scope.busy = false;
        }
})`